# APEX Unit Test - test data with roll-up totals not as expected

Tags: apex, soql, unit-test, campaign, roll-up-summary

I'm trying to write a Unit Test on a controller method that essentially runs a SOQL query on a Child object with `__r` reference to the Parent `Campaign` object. For test structure, I'm using a `for` loop to create 10 `Opportunity` objects for a test `Campaign` object. I'm concerned with the field `NumberOfOpportunities`.

I expect `System.assertEquals(10, response.Campaign__r.NumberOfOpportunities);` to *pass*, but it **Fails**.

Here's my code:

```
 @IsTest
private class FundsRequestCostsControllerTest {
    @IsTest
    static void testBehavior() {
        Campaign campaign = new Campaign();
        campaign.Name = 'test campaign';
        insert campaign;

        for(Integer i=0; i<10; i++){
            Opportunity opportunity = new Opportunity();
            opportunity.Name = 'test opp' + i;
            opportunity.Amount = 100 + i;
            opportunity.StageName = 'Closed Won';
            opportunity.CloseDate = date.today();
            opportunity.Campaign = campaign;
            insert opportunity;
        }

        FundsRequest__c request = new FundsRequest__c();
        request.Campaign__c = campaign.Id;

        Account account = new Account();
        account.Name = 'test account';

        insert account;

        request.Account__c = account.Id;

        insert request;

        Test.startTest();

        FundsRequest__c response = FundsRequestCostsController.getCosts(request.Id);

        Test.stopTest();
        System.assertEquals(10, response.Campaign__r.NumberOfOpportunities);
    }
}
```

Comment: Test methods should also follow best practices of not having dank inside of an iteration

Comment: Ugh not dank - DML

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Here's an article about this [https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Best_Practice:_Avoid_SOQL_Queries_Inside_FOR_Loops](best practice)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Objects are normally related via `Id` values not references so one change to make is to replace this:

```
opportunity.Campaign = campaign;
```

with this:

```
opportunity.CampaignId = campaign.Id;
```

so the Opportunities are related to the Campaign. It is the same pattern as this:

```
request.Campaign__c = campaign.Id;
```

(The Force.com IDE has a dummy file called `salesforce.schema` in the root folder of a project; this seems a reliable place to get the required name from.)

Comment: I think you meant Force.com IDE?

Comment: @KeithC , Can you elaborate a bit on navigating this `salesforce.schema` file? I don't use the Force.com IDE. You're saying to find the field names for key object relations? As to suggest, they don't always follow the `[ObjectName]Id` convention?

Comment: @IanTunbridge The Force.com IDE is the way I usually find the actual names; there may be other tools. You could post a separate question for recommendations. In the Force.com IDE a placekeeper file is created in the project root that when you double click opens an editor that presents the SObjects and when you drill down it fetches the field definitions too.